# Django rest framework extended user profile

Tags: django, rest, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I recently discovered DRF and I'm lost with the quantity of views, viewsets and other possibilities.

I have a Python3/Django 1.8 application with an extended user profile:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class Profile(models.Model):
    GENDER = (
        ('male', _('MALE')),
        ('female', _('FEMALE')),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(default='', max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(default='', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(default='', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to allow external mobile applications connected with oauth2/token Bearer to **get the current connected user's profile** through the api and **editing it** using those routes:

GET or PUT /api/profile
GET or PUT /api/user

My first intention was using only one route for manipulate both models (through /api/profile) but I failed and I'm not sure if it's a good practice to mix two models behind one route.

I tried lot of things. My last attempt was to get the profile like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'groups')

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @list_route(methods=['get', 'post'], permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated])
    def profile(self, request):
        u = User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk)[0]
        p = Profile.objects.filter(user=u)[0]
        return Response({"id": u.id, "first_name": u.first_name, "last_name": u.last_name, "email": u.email,
                     "city": p.city, "country": p.country, "bio": p.bio})

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
```

Problem is: I'm failed trying to implement the same thing for PUT requests. Furthermore I would like to do the security and defensive coding part on the API side and in this situation I don't even using the serializers.

Could you guys help me to find the right thing to do? Do you have any tips, suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: What was the problem when you created a viewset for profile?

Comment: Swagger didn't display any form fields because I didn't find how manually use the serializer and I had to manually check the user data. I would like to delegate the security checks to the serializer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('bio', 'gender', 'city', 'country')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'groups', 'profile')
```

Or if you want it flat:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    bio = serializers.CharField(source='profile.bio')
    gender = serializers.CharField(source='profile.gender')
    #same for the others

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'groups', 'bio', 'gender')
```

I didn't test it, but should be close to what you want, or close to it at least.

Comment: It's close indeed thanks! But I would like to authorize only GET and PUT request and auto-select the current user.

POST /user/profile (modify the current user profile model)
GET /user/profile (modify the current user model)

Comment: Wow this was stupid simple and I've been looking for it for days now. I am new to DRF. Thanks!